# Object or package containing all characters

Tags: r, utf-8, escaping, character, special-characters

Is there an R object or package containing all characters that are available in e.g. UTF-8 encoding that can be accessed somehow?
I am thinking of something similar to this:

```
> object$vowels
 [1] "A" "E" "I" "O" "U" "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
> object$umlauts
[1] "Ä" "Ö" "Ü" "ä" "ö" "ü"
> object$special
[1] "!"   "§"   "$"   "%"   "&"   "/"   ...
```

Basically I want to save the time collecting every possible character there is and classifying it accordingly by hand. I know there is

```
letters[1:26]
```

Are there similar objects for other characters?

Comment: Do you looking for sth like: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Unicode/Unicode.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reference from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), we can create our own function:

```
myFunc <- function(type = "special") {
  # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
  if(type == "special") myRange <- c(32:47, 58:64, 91:96, 123:126) 

  # extend as required
  #if(type == "vowels") myRange <- c(..)

  #return
  unlist(strsplit(intToUtf8(myRange), ""))
}


myFunc(type = "special")
# [1] " "  "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "." 
# [16] "/"  ":"  ";"  "<"  "="  ">"  "?"  "@"  "["  "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "{" 
# [31] "|"  "}"  "~"
```